# Understanding Instruments and Memory Management

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone

I'm in need of understanding how memory is managed in objective C.
I know the basics, if you create it and own it, you must release it yourself.
However, when it gets to code such as:

```
self.storeDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath2];
```

Do I own this? Must I release this memory?

```
self.storeDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath2]; 
//73.3% leak   
totalCharacters = [storeDict count];
tagCounter = 1;

dictKeyArray = [[storeDict allKeys] mutableCopy];
//13.3% leak
```

When Instruments puts a bunch of percentages next to the highlighted leaks, what does that tell me? Does it tell me the size of the leak relative to the total amount of memory leaked?

And one last thing.. Is it normal for the amount of allocated memory to continuously rise? Or should it stabilize somewhere?
Thanks for all the help! Everything is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, you only own objects returned by methods whose names begin with "alloc", "new", "copy", or "mutableCopy". Of course, you also own anything to which you send `-retain`.  Exceptions to these rules should be called out in the documentation for the non-conforming methods.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1

Instruments attributes a leak to the line where the object was created.  However, that's not necessarily the code which leaked the object. If the pointer to the object was passed to some other code and that code did not balance its retains and releases, then that code is responsible for the leak.  Instruments can show you the history of retains and releases for a specific object, and you'll have to review those to see which code is not discharging its ownership responsibilities properly.

Also, if an object is owned by another object and it's really that second object that was leaked, then everything it owned will have leaked "transitively" as it were. So, look for higher-level objects which have leaked before trying to track down low-level objects which have leaked. Often, it is the objects which have leaked fewer instances which are the root of a graph of leaked objects.

Whether it is normal for memory to keep rising or to stabilize, that depends a little. Usually, memory usage should stabilize. However, if your app really is doing more and more, then it may be normal for its memory usage to keep increasing. For example, if an app is receiving data over the network and accumulating results as it does so, then its memory usage would likely rise as more data arrives. But if it doesn't stop at some reasonable point, that's a problem. On an iOS device, the system will eventually kill it.